# Unable to Convert XMLData into Dictionary Form

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have an XML file and I am converting the data into NSString using this code:-

```
NSString *strPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VISG" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strPath];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

The problem I am facing is I am getting the string with all the XMLValues but I am unable to convert that string into Dictionary. I have used XMLReader but it always returns me nil . I have tried the below two methods for converting the string which I ma getting from NSdata but it always throws nil

```
dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:string
                                           options:XMLReaderOptionsProcessNamespaces
                                         error:&error];
dict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:string error:nil]
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem. Or can you please tell me some more libraries other than XMLReader for parsing the XMLfile.

Comment: `error:&error];` And what is the error? Since `dict` is `nil`, I guess that `error` isn't.

Comment: you should first check the &error. it is nil or not.

Comment: @Larme I have checked the XML file online and it said XML file is invalid